# Magento 2.1.0 problem with country options

Tags: checkout

I have a problem with checkout page more specific to country options. In **Backend** it is set all for "Romania" but in **Frontend** is showing another countries.

I use Magento 2.1.0 and i linked 2 image to show my problem.

Country settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Semal.jpg

Frontend:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqcrk.jpg

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: When you inspect the dropdown element for olanda is it country code Netherlands?

Comment: Yes:
https://i.imgur.com/i7VsoVt.jpg